# Possible number of outcomes for a round-robin

Tags: combinatorics

I'm trying to find out how many unique results there can be for a 4-person round-robin, without disambiguating for players.
The players can either win, tie, or lose.

If we had 4 players A,B,C,D and we disambiguated between them, then it would be easy:

- Player A has three outcomes against players B,C,D
- Player B has three outcomes against players C,D
- Player C has three outcomes against player D

So there are $3^6 = 729$ possible outcomes.

But if we do not disambiguate the players, i.e. we just care about the possible unique standings that can arise, I'm not sure how to go about this.

Comment: There are $6$ matches. Each one of them either has a W/L outcome or D(Draw). So $2^6$.

Comment: Can you be more specific about the definition of the unique standing?

Comment: @user That is, any two results that have exactly the same set of 4-player standings are considered to be the same.

Answer (score 1):

$\def\x{\Large\bullet}$
I will assume that two standings are different if there is no permutation of the labels $ABCD$ which transforms one standing into the other.

Obviously if there are no players with equivalent standing all 24 possible permutations of $ABCD$ will transform a table into a new one. Therefore it suffices to count the standings with some players having equivalent standings. In the tables below $2$ means the win, $1$ means the draw and $0$ means the loss.

**The standings with 4 equivalent players.**

There are two such standings:
$$\scriptsize
\begin{array}{cccc}
\x&1&1&1\\
1&\x&1&1\\
1&1&\x&1\\
1&1&1&\x\\
\end{array}
\quad\text{and}\quad
\begin{array}{cccc}
\x&2&1&0\\
0&\x&2&1\\
1&0&\x&2\\
2&1&0&\x\\
\end{array}
$$
The standings have $1$ and $6$ representations (tables), respectively (in the second table the three results of the first player can be arbitrarily permuted to obtain a new table).

**The standings with 3 equivalent players.**

They are:
$$\scriptsize
\begin{array}{cccc}
\x&Z&Z&Z\\
2-Z&\x&1&1\\
2-Z&1&\x&1\\
2-Z&1&1&\x\\
\end{array}
\quad\text{and}\quad
\begin{array}{cccc}
\x&Z&Z&Z\\
2-Z&\x&2&0\\
2-Z&0&\x&2\\
2-Z&2&0&\x\\
\end{array}
$$
where $Z$ can take on the values of $0,2$ and $0,1,2$ for the first and second tables, respectively. There are $2\times4$ and $3\times 8$ tables of the first and second kind, respectively ($2$ or $3$ stays for the choice of $Z$, $4$ for the choice of the "special" player. In the second case there is additional factor $2$ for the possible permutation of $2$ and $0$ by equivalent players.)

**The standings with two pairs of equivalent players.**

Observe that the result of the game between the equivalent players can be only the draw. Therefore we have:
$$\scriptsize
\begin{array}{cccc}
\x&1&2&2\\
1&\x&2&2\\
0&0&\x&1\\
0&0&1&\x\\
\end{array}
\quad\text{and}\quad
\begin{array}{cccc}
\x&1&2&1\\
1&\x&1&2\\
0&1&\x&1\\
1&0&1&\x\\
\end{array}
$$
There are $6$ and $12$ tables of the first and second kind, respectively ($6$ stays for the choice of a pair, in the second case we can permute $2$ and $1$ in the "inter-pair" part of the table).

**The standings with one pair of equivalent players.**

As above the result of the game between the equivalent players is the draw and the most general type of the table is:
$$\scriptsize
\begin{array}{cccc}
\x&1&X&Y\\
1&\x&X&Y\\
2-X&2-X&\x&Z\\
2-Y&2-Y&2-Z&\x\\
\end{array}
$$
where either $X\ne Y$ or $Z\ne1$. There are altogether 12 such standings. However two of them appear to be of the class with three equivalent players (this happens  when $X=1$ and $Z=Y\ne1$). Thus there remain $10$ inequivalent standings with $12$ tables per each standing.

Let us accumulate the above findings in a table:
$$
\begin{array}{|c|r|r|}
\#\text{equiv. players}&\#\text{standings}&\#\text{reps.}\\
\hline
4&1&1\\
&1&6\\
\hline
3&2&4\\
&3&8\\
\hline
2\times2&1&6\\
&1&12\\
\hline
2&10&12\\
\hline
\end{array}
$$

Thus we have altogether $19$ standings with total number of $177$ representatives. From this we can obtain the number of standings with no equivalent players:
$$
\frac{729-177}{24}=23.
$$

Thus, in total there are $19+23=42$ unique standings.